# array-contains not fetching result in 2 Dimensional array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am saving data in a Document like the below image. I want to fetch the records from array `notifyArray` , `ctg` where `array-contains` **Burger**.

This is the code i am trying :

```
  firebase.firestore().collection(`notifications`)
  .where("notifyArray", "array-contains", 'Burger')
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot=> {           
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
      console.log(doc.data());
      console.log("Search result");
      var data = Object.assign(doc.data(), {docid : doc.id})
      this.goalList1.push(data);
  });
  console.log(this.goalList1);
  });
```

But it is not returning any result. Ideally it should return 2 records.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `notifyArray` is an array of maps, each map containing two properties.  Firestore doesn't support querying of map properties in an array.  You can only search for the entire contents of the map, which means you have to know all of the values of all of its fields.

What you can do instead is make a new array that contains **only** the string values of the `food` property in the map, then query that array instead.

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection(`notifications`)
    .where("foodArray", "array-contains", 'Burger')
```

Above, the query is expecting that there is an array of strings called `foodArray`.

Comment: Let me try to answer the way you have explained. I have array of maps  and i want to filter maps via properties, the other way you explained, i am aware of that

Comment: As I said, you can't filter based on the contents of a map field in an array.  You will need a new field to support this query.

Comment: thanks for the guidance, can you please guide me here too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487697/firestore-functions-or-triggers