# Design decision between Firestore functions or triggers

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Client side platform I am using is Web Angular.

When I create a Task, I add followers in it, for example 3 followers.

Now once Task is saved, I want to push 3 records in 3 different documents.

1. Do I create a for loop at client side?
2. Use Firestore triggers? It's in beta and can take up to 10 seconds delay
3. Firestore functions ?

What is the best way to cope with this requirement?

### Edit 1

How do I arrange the `array union` code in batch commit ?

My current code

```
  var washingtonRef = firebase.firestore().collection("notifications").doc(this.loggedInuser);
washingtonRef.update({
  notifyArray: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
    { food: "Margarita", ctg: "Pizza" },
    { food: "Chicken Burger", ctg: "Burger" },
    { food: "Veg Burger", ctg: "Burger" }
    )
});
```

In batch

```
batch_write(){

// Get a new update batch
var batch = firebase.firestore().batch();
var sfRef = firebase.firestore().collection("notifications").doc("1");
batch.update(sfRef, **HOW DO I PLACE here arrayUnion like above** ??);

//another update batch

// and another update batch

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    console.log("batch commited successful");
});

}
```

If i am doing it like below, it gives error `Cannot find name 'notifyArray'.` -

```
var sfRef = firebase.firestore().collection("notifications").doc("1");
batch.update(sfRef, 
  notifyArray: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
    { food: "Margarita", ctg: "Pizza" },
    { food: "Chicken Burger", ctg: "Burger" },
    { food: "Veg Burger", ctg: "Burger" }
    )  
  );
```

Comment: Which platform? Web, Android, iOS, from a server, ...

Comment: client side platform is web angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to write/update the four documents (writing the Task one and writing/updating the three followers documents).

You have to do as follows:

```
var batch = firebase.firestore().batch();
var sfRef = firebase.firestore().collection("notifications").doc("1");
batch.update(sfRef, 
  { notifyArray: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
    { food: "Margarita", ctg: "Pizza" },
    { food: "Chicken Burger", ctg: "Burger" },
    { food: "Veg Burger", ctg: "Burger" }
    )
   }  
  );

var sfRef = firebase.firestore().collection("notifications").doc("2");
batch.update(sfRef, 
  { notifyArray: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
    { food: "Margarita", ctg: "Pizza" },
    { food: "Chicken Burger", ctg: "Burger" },
    { food: "Veg Burger", ctg: "Burger" }
    )
   }  
  );

batch.commit().then(function () {
    console.log("batch commited successful");
});
```

Comment: alright, so according to you, my approach shall be client side and not to use any functions or triggers

Comment: If you can do it client side, yes it’s the most straightforward way. You may also consider transactions if you want to avoid concurrent updates.

Comment: I have edited my question and place my code there, please guide how do i manage to put that in batch update

Comment: See the update: you need to pass an object as the second argument of the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch?authuser=0#update) method. Don't forget to include the task document as well in the batched write.

Comment: thank you for the answer,  can you please guide me here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488555/sending-push-notification-from-angular-and-firebase-server