# Sending push notification from Angular and Firebase server

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to send Push Notification using Postman. I don't want to use a separate server and send Push Notifications using PHP.

Current using `POST` method - `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

As I am using Firestore as database and Firebase as hosting to host my app

How can I send notifications using Firebase server. Below is what I am using via Postman to send a notification at the moment.

```
{
 "to": "my token id",
 "data": {
  "title": "Push Message",
  "message": "This is notification will change tab",
  "sound": "default",
  "badge": 2,
  "page": "offline-storage",
  "taskid":156
 },
 "notification":{
    "title": "Push Message",
  "message": "This is notification will change tab",
  "sound": "default",
  "badge": 2,
  "page": "offline-storage",
  "taskid":156
 }
}
```

Screenshot attached
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this official Cloud Function sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Comment: user2828442, could you give this a go, based on the recommended material from @Renaud? I think this question is rather broad at the moment, and needs an attempt (plus a problem statement) to be answerable (at least in a way that is useful to future readers).